# Introducing animals to a terraforming Mars by air-drop

Tags: planets, fauna, ecology, terraforming, aircraft

So, the moment has arrived: Mars is habitable. Plants, fungi, and even insects have been introduced by air-drop, along with fish and crustaceans introduced as eggs. However, what larger animals could be introduced by this method?

Comment: In a rather famous episode of the Second World War, on 20 May 1940 National-Socialist Germany [introduced by airdrop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Crete) 22,000 great apes , *Homo fallschirmjaeger*, into the island of Crete. They won. Therefore, it is obviously possible to airdrop on a large scale megafauna at least to about 100 kg apiece.

Comment: What does "air drop" mean here?

Comment: Even before the air drop, the elephant must be launched into space. Can it survive the launch? And then Mars is a long way aways. Can the elephant survive six months in a tin can without going mad and dying?

Comment: If Mars is habitable, and it's not by magic, or by alien interference, you already have high-capacity advanced space infrastructure , both on Earth, and all over the red planet.  You won't need to airdrop animals, because it's straightforward for your civilization to soft-land them, or grow them planetside. It's not like you'll be sending unmodified animals, anyway.

Comment: Fish get pretty freaking big.  Bigger than me, and that is saying something.  They all start small.

Comment: I am a firm believer that [anything I find on YouTube must be true](https://youtu.be/1m-7GrtuOUA). So all you need to do is push the elephants out of the plane. But on a more serious note, if [we can parachute tanks](https://youtu.be/50cpPAVoxJQ) then I feel it's completely believable that you can air drop large creatures. @notovny is right, if you can terraform Mars there are likely easier ways to do it... but I can suspend my disbelief for this.

Answer (score 3):

Mars is habitable! Well done, that was the hard part.  That means it now has a nice thick atmosphere.  This makes getting to the surface easier overall, but harder in some respects.  You won't need fuel to help you land, but you will need to re-enter.

But, re-entry has been done multiple times, and successfully landed 100kg animals on a planet (Earth), and that is with twentieth century technology.  There should be no problem with your level of tech in softly landing (by parachute or retrorocket, or reentry plane that morphs into a glider or something else) animals of basically any size you care to choose.

Sure, getting a blue whale to Mars would be a challenge, but it should not be beyond your level of technology... but is this what you really want? It is more a matter of cost/benefit rather than what is possible.

In short, it is quite possible for an elephant to be parachuted onto a planet from a plane that is flying above the land.  But wouldn't it be easier just to land the plane?

Comment: And I think realistically you'd want to consider how the animal extracts itself from the landing device. Some kind of crate that lands and "deploys" (collapses in a designed fashion or opens a gate) would probably be best.

Comment: That should be achievable for a civilisation that can terraform a planet!

Comment: "Marketing says no, you airdrop it."

Answer (score 1):

Considering the technological advances that would have to be in place to have Mars habitable, the year must be pretty far into the future. It's safe to say that the tech we have now would either be obsolete or have advanced enough to solve a wealth of problems that you can now employ merrily that would circumvent the need to air ship any animals or plants to Mars in a viable, sentient form.

We have seed repositories of much vastness on Earth now. Let's assume that Mars being habitable was a decision out of necessity and not just some rich *&*^$ wanting to get there first to claim the whole thing for themselves...

Whatever triggered the need to get our a**es to Mars would also have spawned the necessity to preserve all known living things in the most logical archive we have today, and potentially in the year your story takes place. So you would most likely have all the seeds well preserved, and any animal life would most likely have had its building blocks cryo-preserved as well.

I think it would be easier to transport the incubators and re-constitution chambers and then re-grow the creatures you need in labs and habitats that introduce them to the environments slowly so they can properly acclimate. Otherwise, it may be possible that moving a creature all the way to Mars, alive and well, and then getting it to safely land on the surface, could very well end up being the environmental shock that kills it, assuming it wasn't eaten up by the other creatures that have already safely landed, or dies off in the vastness of nothingness surrounding it.

Terraforming is one thing. But ambient environments would be the kind of thing that would take eons to match what we have now, or would have to be in some kind of fabricated biosphere. Otherwise, the air may be breathable to some degree, but everything else is still Mars. Even if you could get a Gazelle to live through the trip, you would need a huge number of them to preserve the herd mentality, and not just have them land, scatter, and die off out of confusion, fear, and circumstance. I would wager there are not a whole lot of animals that would just thrive after being transplanted to a completely foreign environment that is not already well prepared for its existence. Consider the food chain as a general guide. For a creature this big to live, it has to have the things it eats. Those things also need what they eat. And so on down to micro-organisms.

This is not to say that it is impossible to transplant life. I'm just saying that from a biological standpoint it makes a lot more sense to cultivate and raise something in a foreign environment than it is to transport them 55 million miles, dealing with keeping them alive that whole time, and then hoping they live bit by bit as you slowly fill up a planet or region of a planet from space via air drops. That would be the sort of bureaucratic move that would get someone fired long before it got past the planning phase. Especially when they could drop a large pre-fab facility with the cryo preserves and all the necessary equipment to reconstitute them instead for far less risk, and far greater control over the creatures and the environments you would be releasing them into.

So that's my suggestion. Air Drop the foundations for reconstitution, not the living creatures themselves. And while we're at it, you may want to have auto guided landing mechanisms. The concept of air dropping anything that far into the future seems too low tech for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plants, insects etc. it means you manages to get Mars's atmosphere pressures up to around 1 atm.

Now consider that Mars's surface gravity is around 37% that of the Earth's. What it means is that if a human were to parachute from a great height, with that combination of atmospheric pressure and fravity pull the fall would be really sloooooooooooooow. Seriously. The terminal speed with a parachute would be ridiculous and anti-climatic.

So yeah, you could fly around and kick animals out of planes. In real life mankind has sent [cats to Borneo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cat_Drop) and beavers to Idaho (couldn't find a wiki nor other durable link) just like that, so on a lower gravity setting this might be safe for larger animals such as even bears and moose.